# New words after pdf copy-paste

Tags: pdf, clipboard

I have a pdf file. Then i select and copy "K([2.2.2]crypt)]5[Co2Sn17".
But in clipboard there is "KACHTUNGTRENUNG([2.2.2]crypt)]5ACHTUNGTRENUNG[Co2Sn17".

Any ideas what is "ACHTUNGTRENUNG"? Is it a kind of protection?

Comment: Its german for "attention separation"^^

Answer (score 1):

There likely are a few extra (invisible) characters in the file. When you copy the text, the application you use to copy translates the characters in the PDF file into something that can be stored on the clipboard. Most likely that happens by translating every character into the unicode string stored in the PDF file for that character in the used font.

For most normal characters the Unicode string should be the same as the character you visually see; here you probably have invisible spaces in the PDF file that are called "achtungtrenung" in the font.

If you have the PDF file available somewhere, I'll be happy to take a look and verify this is indeed what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

It's extra characters between lines.

You can try the [PDF Copy Paste](http://www.PDFCopyPaste.com) software, and see if your desired portion can be converted to text of your preferences.